# Is there a safer command to delete files and directories other than rm -rf?

Tags: linux

I've been reading how running `rm -rf` to delete files and directories isn't a good idea because of how dangerous it can be, but can't seem to find a consensus on how to safely delete files and directories through the terminal. Is there another command built into Linux that does this safely?

Comment: What exactly would "safely" mean?

Comment: I was reading how accidentally typing `rm -rf /` could delete a lot files on your system. Basically, a way to delete files, but if you accidentally type the wrong command, it won't damage your system.

Comment: This is one of those great power -> great responsibility deals. Don't delete everything recursively from the root of your file system.

Comment: In Unix, a lot of tools are destructive, but it doesn't mean they're bad. Some of the destructive commands that is very useful are `dd`, `rm`, `mkfs`, `parted rm`, and a lot more to list here. These tools make work easier but care should always be taken.

Comment: In most cases, accidental deletion from `/` happens with scripts that are poorly written. Consider this command `rm -rf "${mypath}/*"`. If the variable `mypath` is empty then the command will translate to `rm -rf "/*"`. The safe solution to this is not removing the recursive delete but by checking and validating `myvar`.

Comment: If you use the `find` command, you can be much more selective of what you are deleting  `find ~/my_projects/abcd/images/* -maxdepth 1 -name '*.png' -type f -delete`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider using the `-i` or `-I` options, ie.

```
$ rm -i foo
$ rm -I foo
```

Those tell `rm` to be *interactive*, prompting you to confirm deletion of files.

From the `rm(1)` manpage:

```
       -i     prompt before every removal

       -I     prompt once before removing  more  than  three  files,  or  when
              removing recursively; less intrusive than -i, while still giving
              protection against most mistakes
```

For example:

```
$ mkdir -p ~/foo/{bar,baz}        # make some dirs
$ touch ~/foo/{bar,baz}/{1,2,3}   # add some empty files
$ rm -ir ~/ foo                   # note the "accidental" space between `~/` and `foo`
rm: descend into directory '/home/uz0r/'? y      # haven't noticed yet...
rm: remove regular file '/home/uz0r/.bashrc'?    # ...wait, what?
```

*"Hold on... I told you to delete `$HOME/foo`, not `$HOME`! Or did I...?"*

So you made a typo, but `-i` saved you from an accident. Now you can tell `rm` to stop, then try again after correcting the typo.

> **Be careful using `-f`!** It counteracts the above safety nets by telling `rm` to "never prompt":
>
> ```
>        -f, --force
>               ignore nonexistent files and arguments, never prompt
> ```

Answer (score 1):

Create yourself a trash bin for your deleted objects.

```
    mkdir ~/trash
    mv xyz ~/trash
```

You can recover, just be aware that some privileges may change on the files.